# What is the 'Const' applicative functor useful for?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I've just found `Const` in the documentation of `Control.Applicative`, but I have a hard time working out where this is useful, over just using `Monoid` directly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's rather useful when combined with `Traversable`.

```
getConst . traverse Const :: (Monoid a, Traversable f) => f a -> a
```

That's the general recipe for glomming a bunch of stuff together. It was one of the use cases which convinced me that it was worth separating `Applicative` from `Monad`. I needed stuff like generalized `elem`

```
elem :: Eq x => x -> Term x -> Bool
```

to do occur-checking for a `Traversable Term` parametrized by the representation of free variables. I kept changing the representation of `Term` and I was fed up modifying a zillion traversal functions, some of which were doing accumulations, rather than effectful mapping. I was glad to find an abstraction which covered both.

Comment: http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html section 4 is a good reference for the traverse trick

Comment: Doesn't `foldMap id` produce the same result with less constraints (`Foldable` instead of `Traversable`)?

Comment: Indeed, that's why `Foldable` exists. However, it's rather useful that everything `Traversable` is `Foldable`, with the above being the construction of `foldMapDefault`. Plug: SHE supports `DefaultSuperclassInstances`, so that everything `Traversable` is by silent default made `Foldable` in that way.

Comment: Which can also be written: `(^. traverse)`. Obvious to many, I'm sure, but perhaps useful to others, like me, who don't always find some of these expressions easy to read.

Answer (score 7):

It's useful when you have a function or data structure that works for all (`Applicative`) `Functor`s, and wish to reuse it in a degenerate sense. It's analogous to passing in `const` or `id` to functions that work given arbitrary functions.

[Van Laarhoven lenses](http://www.twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/cps-functional-references) are defined in terms of arbitrary Functors, and use `Const` to derive a field accessor (and the equally trivial `Identity` to derive a field updater).

[`Traversable`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Data-Traversable.html) types, as pigworker mentions, are another example of this.

Answer (score 7):

As dave4420 mentions, implementing accessor and updater for Van Laarhoven lenses involves `Const` functor. To elaborate:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Identity

-- The definition of Van Laarhoven lenses:
type Lens a b = forall f . Functor f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)

-- Getter passes the Const functor to the lens:
get :: Lens a b -> a -> b
get l = getConst . (l Const)

-- Updater passes the Identity functor to the lens:
modify :: Lens a b -> (b -> b) -> (a -> a)
modify l f = runIdentity . l (Identity . f)

set :: Lens a b -> b -> (a -> a)
set l r = modify l (const r)

-- Example: -------------------------------------------

data Person = Person { _name :: String, _age :: Int }
  deriving Show

name :: Lens Person String
name f (Person n a) = fmap (\x -> Person x a) (f n)

age :: Lens Person Int
age f (Person n a) = fmap (\x -> Person n x) (f a)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let john = Person "John" 34
    print $ get age john
    print $ set name "Pete" john
```

Answer (score 2):

As Gabriel Gonzalez points out, Const is used to provide Getters to lenses. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.0/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html. There you only use that Const is a functor.

For traversals, you need the full Applicative behaviour, and it becomes what pigworker described in another answer.